# Override hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, jar, config

I have 2 configuration files hibernate1.cfg.xml and another one hibernate2.cfg.xml
Now I have a jar that has the method to open connections (reading the connection details from the two files above) between two DBs and transfer data.

The hibernate1.cfg.xml and hibernate2.cfg.xml names are fixed.
Now I have another main method which calls the first jars method. 
Now, the configuration files need to be overriden.

Like in eclipse, if we have a config file in jar. If we create another config file with same name and put in the resources with the same directory structure, it gets overriden.

I tried loading in classpath using URLClassLoader. I cant load it in classpath even.

How can I do this? Please help.